# Notational confusion in definition of likelihood function

Tags: probability, likelihood, notation

From [Alex Graves Ch. 2](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/preprint.pdf):

$(x,z)$ are input, target pairs in the training set $S$, and $S$ is drawn from the input-target distribution $D$.  I am confused by the following line:

$p(S|w)=\prod_{(x,z)\in S}^{ }p(z|x,w)$

Is $p(S|w)$ the density $(x,z)$ conditioned on parameter $w$?  The RHS of the expression suggests that $p(S|w)$ is the likelihood function $L(w)=p(z|x;w)$, or the probability of observing $z$ conditioned on input $x$ and parameters $w$.  However, I fail to see how $p(S|w)=p(z|x;w)$.  $x$ is being treated as given in one, but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I'm guessing $w$ is some shape parameter describing the relationship between $z$ and $x$ (for example, maybe $z \sim N(w,x)$). The goal of the likelihood maximization is to produce an estimate $\hat w$ of $w$. For this, only the relationship of $z$ to $x$ is what matters. The distribution of $x$ itself is *a priori* information -- the likelihood maximization doesn't have to describe the true distribution $x \sim X$ or the likelihood of getting the observed values $x_i$. The observed values of $x$ are given; they are what they are. What the likelihood *does* care about is how the observations $z$ depend on the given $x$, and so it depends on $p(z | x,w)$, which is the conditional probability of z conditioned on $x$ and $w$. In the normal distribution example I gave above, this would just be a gaussian pdf
$$
p(z|x,w) = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(z-w)^2}{2x^2}}
$$